# Dont know how to properly pass a table to thread

Tags: c, pthreads

basically my goal is this program

> The purpose of the exercise is to build a program in C which will generates four threads that will compute some sums of the elements of a table. The table will contain 1,000,000 random integers and each of the four threads will take over its own separate section of the table (which, of course, it will consist of ¼ of the elements in the table). The main thread will must wait for the completion of the four threads and then will calculates the total sum of the elements in the table by adding them some sums calculated from the threads

I finished most of the part but not Im stuck to how i should pass the table of 1million ints to the thread

my code is this one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int table[1000000]= for(int i=0; i<1000000;i++){

    table[i]=(rand() %10) + 1;}

void* summary(void* arg){
    int index = *(int*)arg;
    int sum = 0;  
    for (int j = 0; j < 250000; j++) {
        sum += table[index + j];
    }
    printf("Local sum: %d\n", sum);
    *(int*)arg = sum;
pthread_exit(arg); 
}

int main(){
    int i;
    pthread_t th[4];
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int* a = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
        *a = i * 250000; 
        if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &summary, a) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to create thread");
        }
    }
    int globalSum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int* result;
        if (pthread_join(th[i], (void**) &result) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to join thread");            
        }                                      
        globalSum += *result;
        free(result);
    }
    printf("Global sum: %d\n", globalSum);
    return 0;

}
```

i tried making the table global but it didnt compiled
how should i pass the table ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code is not valid. You cannot initialized an array with a loop. You also cannot have a loop or any other statement outside of a function. You can make the array global but you need to initialize it in `main` or some other function before you pass the start index to the threads.

Comment: This must be the new C...int table[1000000]= for(int i=0; i<1000000;i++){...

Answer (score 0):

You ask about passing the array to the thread, but your question is not at all related to that.
Your compile errors indicate that you cannot initialize the array the way you do it.
In C you can only have declarations and definitions outside of functions.
Any statement (control structure, function call, etc.) must be done inside a function body.

Therefore you must change your code like this:

```c
#include <time.h>
...
int table[1000000];
...
int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        table[i]= (rand() % 10) + 1;
    }
...
}
```

Please note the added call to `srand` that should be used once in your program before you use `rand`. Otherwise you might get the same sequence on every run of your program.

The rest of your code looks fine. You do not pass the array to the threads at all but only pass the start of the range for each thread. That is OK.